# Questions regarding log4net's AdoNetAppender

Tags: log4net

I have log4net logging to my database after following a few examples and tutorials. A couple of things are unclear to me.

In the example on [the log4net page](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) it lists the following node in the configuration area.

```
 <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
 </parameter>
```

This parameter appears to pass an empty string to the database even when I log from within an exception.

Can someone clarify what should be logged to this field and when?

Also that example also has 'thread' being logged to the database as a varchar(255). What I get in that field is an integer. I'm not familiar with threads. Can I just store this as an int? Would this end up being a string in some cases?

```
   <parameter>
     <parameterName value="@thread" />
     <dbType value="String" />
     <size value="255" />
     <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
       <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
     </layout>
   </parameter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for exception to be populated, you need to use the correct overload

for example, if you use

```
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    log.Error("Error saving details" , ex);
    ...   
 }
```

then the exception column of your database will be set to ex.ToString()

If you use

```
 log.Error("Error saving details " + ex.ToString());
```

then exception is not filled it

As for the thread identifier, this should be a string in your database. The default thread id is an integer, but you can explicitly name the thread,

eg

```
 var ts = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(InitialiseDatabase);
 var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(ts);
 thread.Name = "Initialising Database";
```

It is a good idea to name your threads, as it makes filtering/indentifying much easier.